# Does the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials hold in any ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Fundamental theorem of Symmetric polynomials:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $e_0,...,e_n$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials of $R[X_1,...,X_n]$.
>
> Let $\Phi:R[X_1,...,X_n]\rightarrow R[X_1,...,X_n]$ be the morphism of rings and $R$-modules such that $\Phi(X_i)=e_i$
>
> Then $\Phi:R[X_1,...,X_n]\rightarrow R[X_1,...,X_n]^{S_n}$ is bijective.

Does this also hold in an arbitrary ring $R$?

Wikipedia states the theorem when $R$ is commutative, but I couldn't find which part of the proof given there uses commutativity of $R$ when I checked the proof carefully.

Comment: Anyway, how define a polynomial ring over a non-commutative ring? The variables commute each other and commute with the elements of $R$?

Comment: $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ is formally the monoid ring $R[\mathbb{N}^n]$. And yes they commute since $\mathbb{N}^n$ is commutative. More generally variables $X_1,...,X_n$ are in the the center of $R[X_1,...,X_n]$.